# How to add logstash grok filter and field

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I'm using Filebeat -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch -> Kibana to have an overview of my glassfish log file.

Here is my Filebeat Configuration. 
http://pastie.org/10958269

```
############################# Filebeat ######################################
filebeat:
  # List of prospectors to fetch data.
  prospectors:
    paths:
    - /Users/mmlug/Documents/univeristy/runtime/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
input_type: log
exclude_lines: ["^DBG"]

multiline:
  pattern: (?m)\[\#\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|%{LOGLEVEL:Log Level}\|%{DATA:server_version}\|%{JAVACLASS:Class}\|%{DATA:thread}\|%{DATA:message_detail}\|\#\]
  negate: true
  match: after

  output:
  ### Logstash as output
  logstash:
     # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

  logging:

  shipper:
```

My log message look like this.

```
[#|2016-11-01T11:29:33.347+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|com.MachineProxy|_ThreadID=226;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|proxy started|#]
```

My current pattern look like this. I have tested with http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

```
(?m)\[\#\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|%{LOGLEVEL}\|%{DATA:server_version}\|%{JAVACLASS}\|%{DATA:thread}\|%{DATA:message_detail}\|\#\]
```

I want to have a fields in Kibana for "DateTime", "Log Level", "Server version", "Java Class Name", "Thread" and "Message detail"

```
2016/11/01 14:59:10.672190 publish.go:109: DBG  Publish: {
 "@timestamp": "2016-11-01T14:59:04.606Z",
 "beat": {
 "hostname": "localhost",
 "name": "localhost"
 },
 "count": 1,
"fields": null,
"input_type": "log",
"message": "[#|2016-11-    01T15:59:02.991+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|com.MachineProxy|_ThreadID=227;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|MachineProxy touched.|#]\n",
"offset": 1671903,
"source": "../logs/server.log",
"type": "log"
}
```

My Logstash configurations in ELK docker container.

```
root@4569cf1f66ab:/etc/logstash/conf.d# 
01-lumberjack-input.conf.backup  02-beats-input.conf  10-syslog.conf  11-   nginx.backup  30-output.conf
```

02-beats-input.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => false
    #ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-beats.crt"
    #ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-beats.key"
  }
}
```

10-syslog.conf

```
filter {
 if [type] == "log" {
  grok {
   match => { "message", "(?m)\[\#\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|%{LOGLEVEL:Log Level}\|%{DATA:server_version}\|%{JAVACLASS:Class}\|%{DATA:thread}\|%{DATA:message_detail}\|\#\]" }
  add_field => [ "Log level", "%{LOGLEVEL:Log Level}" ]
}
syslog_pri { }
date {
  match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Thomas

Comment: The result you are showing does not seemed to have gone through the grok filter. Could you add your configuration file (preferably edited to just the relevant parts)

Comment: @baudsp I updated my questions with all of my configurations files.

Comment: Thanks. With the configuration you posted, it should work, except for the date filter, which is on a field that do not exist (`syslog_timestamp`, use `timestamp` instead) and with the wrong pattern (ISO8601 should work)

Comment: Thanks. I have another error when I start my filebeat. 
INFO Error publishing events (retrying): EOF
INFO send fail.
here is my Logstash logfile: http://pastebin.com/aTCLyDXE 
Any idea where i'm going wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are missing the } for  if [type] == "log" {

Comment: i have updated my 10-syslog.conf filer config. But have the same error. http://pastie.org/10960364

Comment: If you have an error with "Expected one of", your configuration file is still malformed. The location will be indicated, corresponding to the position of the error in the result of the concatenation of the configuration files.